# conflicting types AND previous implicit declaration in C

Tags: c

[The error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cchuk.png)

```
skeleton.c:86:6: warning: conflicting types for ‘verifyWord’ [enabled by default]
 void verifyWord(char nword) {
      ^
skeleton.c:79:3: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘verifyWord’ was here
   verifyWord(nextword);
   ^
```

---

```
void playgame() {
    .
    .
    . 
    strcpy(curword, get_random_word(dictptr));

    for(;;) {
        .
        .
        .
        /*function for nextword if correct*/
        verifyWord(nextword);
        /*                                           */
    } /* end for loop */
    .
    . 
    .
}
```

---

```
void verifyWord(char nword) {
FILE * fp;

fp = fopen ("usedWords.txt", "a+");
fprintf(fp, "%d ", nword);

fclose(fp);
}
```

Hi, this program is supposed to be a mini word game, i am new to C.
Need some help in figuring out how can i avoid the error shown in the imgur image.

the above 2 is a playgame function and a verifyWord function

Please point me in the right direction as i tried declaring above the main:

- verifyWord();
- char verifyWord(void);
- char verifyWord();

Comment: Make sure the prototype for `verifyWord()` is visible to every caller of the function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the function correctly with the arguments you are willing to pass in it.

Let's say for example that `verifyWord` returns `void` and accepts `char pointer` as an argument.

The proper declaration would be:

```
void verifyWord (char *nextWord);
```

And you will use it like:

```
char* nextWord = NULL;

verifyWord(nextword);
```

Your problem is that you didn't tell your compiler how to deal with the function. You need to have explicit declaration, like the one I mentioned above, placed somewhere before the line where you call it, and it has to be within the same scope.

Comment: If you had read the OP's post, you'd have seen that one of the declarations is *implicit*.

Comment: Oh, my bad. Still, this solves the question, since the question is: "Please point me in the right direction as i tried declaring above the main:"